Java Akka Actor stopped receiving of messages when messages count is more
In our Java Spring application, we are using Scala Akka messaging library to send and receive the messages.
In Message we are passing the object to be process.
This sending of objects to receivers happens frequently at every 5 minutes. We are having a cron job which fetches the list of objects to be process.
Then we are sending those objects to the receiver actors. After sometime, we are seeing that receivers are stopped processing the sending messages.
When we restart the application then only it pick the last sent messages and started processing.
Nothing is there in the logs.
Could you let us know why it stopped in between?
akka-version - 2.3.9
akka-actor_2.11-2.3.9.jar
akka-testkit_2.11-2.3.9.jar
we are using tell() method while sending the message
this.actorRef.tell(new Work(message), null);
we are using ask() method to get the response
this.ref.tell(new Work(message), null);
I want to know why it stopped in between. Is there anything I need to modify it to process large number of messages.


public class WorkGroupClient <T>
{
    private final static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(WorkGroupClient.class);
    private final ActorRef ref;
    
    public WorkGroupClient(ActorRef ref)
    {
        this.ref = ref;
    }

    public void send(T message)
    {
        if (message!=null) {
            log.info("STEP: Send Akka message for class : "+message.getClass());
        }
        this.ref.tell(new Work(message), null);
    }
    
    public void sendOnCommit(final T message)
    {
        if (message!=null) {
            log.info("STEP: Send Akka message : "+message.getClass());
        }
        TxUtil.runOnCommit(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                send(message);
            }
        });
    }
    
    public Object ask(T message, long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
    {
        if (message!=null) {
            log.info("STEP: ask message for class : "+message.getClass() ");
        }
        return AkkaUtil.ask(this.ref, new Work(message), timeout, unit);
    }
}


@Bean
    public ActorSystem actorSystem()
    {
        ConfigBuilder builder = new ConfigBuilder();
        Map<String,String> external = Maps.newHashMap();
        Iterator<String> keys = config.getKeys();
        builder.withValues(external);
        if( config.getBoolean(DEBUG_ALL, false) )
        {
            builder.withDebugAll();
        }
        Config config = builder.build();
        ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("myActorSystem", config);
        return system;
    }
    

public abstract class WorkGroupWorker <T> extends UntypedActor
{
    private final static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(WorkGroupWorker.class);

    private final FailureCounter COUNTER = new FailureCounter();
    private volatile T work;
    private final Class<T> type;
    private final String metric;
    
    private volatile boolean complete = false;
    
      @Override
    public final void onReceive(Object msg) throws Exception
    {
        log.info("STEP: onReceive method BEGIN");
        Scope scope = Profiler.start(this.metric);
        try
        {
            if(  msg instanceof Work )
            {
                log.info("STEP: msg is instance of Work");
                Work work = (Work) msg;
                this.work = this.type.cast(work.getTarget());
                log.info("STEP: work = "+work);
                workAssigned();
            } 
            else if ( work != null )
            {
                log.info("STEP: Executing onReceive elseIf for msg class = "+msg.getClass()+", msg = "+msg);
                onMessage(msg); 
            }
            else
            {
                log.info("STEP: Message is null");
                unhandled(msg);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.error("error in processing " + this.metric + " : "  +msg, e);
            COUNTER.count(this.metric, e);
            throw e;
        }
        // treat as non-fatal, normally akka will shutdown with any thread error
        catch ( Error e)
        {
            log.error("critical error in processing " + this.metric + " : "  +msg, e);
            throw new CriticalWorkerFailure("critical error in processing " + this.metric + " : "  +msg, e);
        }
        finally
        {
           Profiler.stop(scope); 
        }
        log.info("STEP: onReceive method    End");
    }
    
    protected void onMessage(Object msg) 
    {
        log.info("STEP: onMessage method BEGIN");
        unhandled(msg);
        log.info("STEP: onMessage method END");
    }

    protected abstract void workAssigned() throws Exception;
    
    protected void workComplete()
    {
        log.info("STEP: workComplete method BEGIN");
        this.work = null;
        getContext().stop(getSelf());
        this.complete = true;
        log.info("STEP: workComplete method END");
    }
    
    public boolean isComplete()
    {
        return complete;
    }
    
    protected T getWork()
    {
        return work;
    }
}




Can you post some actual code, including an outline of the actor that is processing these messages?

Hi @Tim, added the code snippet, please have a look


we are using ask() method to get the response

The ask method sends a message and then waits for a response. So if you are calling send then ask you will be sending two messages and only waiting for one of them.
This is exacerbated by the fact that the actor is overwriting the work field on every message which introduces a race condition.
It looks like you need to remove the send methods and just use ask which will ensure that the actor only processes one message at a time.

send() is our internal method, which invokes Actor's tell method.
public void send(T message)
{
 if (message!=null) {
  log.info("STEP: Send Akka message for class : "+message.getClass());

}
this.ref.tell(new Work(message), null);
}

When I inspect logs, found some other scheduled jobs throwing dead letters.
INFO  [com.test.akka.messaging.impl.SingletonWorkItem] [marketport-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-207] STEP: sender = Actor[akka://mysystem/deadLetters], work = com.test.report.service.messaging.PostCustomizationMessage@bd980dc
INFO  [com.test.akka.messaging.impl.SingletonWorkItem] [marketport-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-207] STEP: sender = Actor[akka://mysystem/deadLetters], work = com.test.report.service.messaging.FileIndexChangeMessage@bd980dc
Will this stops from sending or receiving the messages?

It's really not possible to debug your application here, and the design of that Actor makes it particularly difficult. I strongly suggest avoiding abstract callbacks like this and instead passing an object to the actor the implements the worker behaviour (strategy pattern). This will make the code much easier to understand and debug
